# how to quantify the dependence between two sparse signals?

Tags: probability, correlation, independence, signal-processing, networks

Hi and thank you for your help. I am happy to provide more context/details.

In my research, I have a system that has many sensors `X_1..X_N` and using this information, the system makes a prediction on a value, A. For simplicity, let's assume that A is binary, and please keep in mind that this is a real system I am trying to improve so that means that I can tell whether A was right or wrong (the system can be checked against "ground truth").

Now each sensor makes measurement sporadically (not necessarily randomly, but definitely not some obvious pattern) for reasons that are too complicated to go into right now. This means that X_1 for example can resemble this: `[2, 5, 1, na, na, 1, na, na, 89 ... ]` where each index of this vector is a time step, and 'na' represents times when the sensor did not take a measurement. This means that the vector actually contains two sets of information: the value of each individual measurement, and when the measurements were done. There is a third value (but that's not important for now) which is about how much effort each sensor put into collecting this information.

Now my problem is that I want to measure the dependence between X's. i.e. given a specific vector of measurement from, say, X_4, what is the probability that X_10 was influenced by X_4. Specifically, I am looking for a number (could be a probability, or a correlation coefficient) that would say that X_10 was influenced by X_4, and I want this number for all pairs of X's.

What I am trying to do is to factor in these influences into the system that is trying to make a decision. Since I know the ground truth, I can tell how good my "dependence measure" is.

I think this is an interesting general problem and I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you!